# How to make turtles/people following a schedule in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

So I am making a code that simulates the demand in a city.  I am trying to have people move from home to work based on the probability of them leaving at that time.  And if they don't move at the hour I want them to stay still. I based my destination code on the taxi cab model in Netlogos library.  But since that code generates passengers based on the probability and my code has a fixed number of people I am getting people with the destination of nobody.  Here is the code I have right now.

```
globals[
  ; phase counter
  BD
  demand
  demand-lawn
  demand-total
  daycounter
  all-phases
  current-phase
  phase-counter
  
  ; patch agentsets for districts and zones of a city

  school-zones
  commercial-zones
  low-residential-zones
  mid-residential-zones
  high-residential-zones
]

breed [ people person ]
breed [ buildings building ]

buildings-own [
  capcity
  ]

people-own [
 destination-patch-passenger
  age
  count-down
  random-number
  start-place
  is-female?
  activity
  ; time when the passenger is picked
  tick-at-pickup
  current-trip-duration
  trip-duration-lst
  ; location information about pickup road
  pickup-on-horizontal?
  pickup-on-vertical? ; destination coordinates
  d-xcor
  d-xcor2
  d-ycor
  d-ycor2 ; pickup coordinates

]

patches-own[
  ; patch identity check
  is-road?
  is-intersection?
  is-traffic-light?
  ; district and zone characteristics
  is-school?
  is-high-residential?
  is-mid-residential?
  is-low-residential?
  is-commercial?
  draw-road-line
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-globals
  setup-patches
  setup-people
  reset-ticks

end


to go
  people-movement
  report-current-phase
  
  tick

end
to setup-patches
  ask patches[
    make-grid
  build-zones
  ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Build Urban Zones ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to build-zones
  ; residential zones
  set commercial-zones patches with [
    (pycor < -3 or pycor > 3) or (pxcor < -3 or pxcor > 3)
  ]
    ask commercial-zones [
    set is-mid-residential? false
    set is-high-residential? false
    set is-low-residential? false
    set is-school? false
    set is-commercial? true
    set pcolor [ 207 207 207]
  ]
  ; cbd zones: center
  set school-zones patches with [
    pxcor = 0 and
    pycor = 0
  ]
  ask school-zones [
    set is-school? true
    set is-mid-residential? false
    set is-high-residential? false
    set is-low-residential? false
    set is-commercial? false
    set pcolor [255 188 121]
  ]
  ; commercial zones

  set low-residential-zones patches with [
    pxcor > -2 and pxcor < 2 and
    pycor > -2 and pycor < 2
  ]
  set low-residential-zones low-residential-zones with [not member? self school-zones]
  ask low-residential-zones [
    set is-low-residential? true
    set is-school? false
    set is-commercial? false
    set is-high-residential? false
    set is-mid-residential? false
    set pcolor [100 200 236] ;; blue
  ]
  set mid-residential-zones patches with [
    pxcor > -3 and pxcor < 3 and
    pycor > -3 and pycor < 3
  ]
  set mid-residential-zones mid-residential-zones with [not member? self school-zones]
  set mid-residential-zones mid-residential-zones with [not member? self low-residential-zones]
  ask mid-residential-zones [
    set is-low-residential? false
    set is-school? false
    set is-commercial? false
    set is-high-residential? false
    set is-mid-residential? true
    set pcolor [150 200 230] ;; blue
  ]
  set high-residential-zones patches with [
    pxcor > -4 and pxcor < 4 and
    pycor > -4 and pycor < 4
  ]
  set high-residential-zones high-residential-zones with [not member? self school-zones]
  set high-residential-zones high-residential-zones with [not member? self low-residential-zones]
  set high-residential-zones high-residential-zones with [not member? self mid-residential-zones]
  ask high-residential-zones [
    set is-low-residential? false
    set is-school? false
    set is-commercial? false
    set is-high-residential? true
    set is-mid-residential? false
    set pcolor [150 255 230] ;; blue
  ]
end

to make-grid
    set pcolor [65 0 0]
   sprout 1 [
    if outline-color != black [
      set color outline-color
    ]
    ifelse top-edges? and right-edges? and bottom-edges? and left-edges? [
      stamp-square-outline
    ] [
      if top-edges?    [ stamp-edge 0   ]
      if right-edges?  [ stamp-edge 90  ]
      if bottom-edges? [ stamp-edge 180 ]
      if left-edges?   [ stamp-edge 270 ]
    ]
    die
  ]
end
to stamp-edge [h]
  set shape "patch-edge"
  set heading h
  stamp
end
to stamp-square-outline
  set shape "square-outline"
  stamp
end


; Helper that takes a list as input
; 1. turn all elements in a list negative
; 2. concatenate both negative and positive lists
to-report create-full-list [lst]
  ;; convert the input list all to negative
  let neg-lst map [i -> i * -1] lst
  ;; concatenate the negative lst with the original pos list
  let full-lst sentence neg-lst lst
  report full-lst
end

to setup-globals
  ask patches [
    set pcolor [207 207 207] ;; cherry red
  ]
  
  ; set up all phases
  set all-phases ["1am" "2am" "3am" "4am" "5am" "6am" "7am" "8am" "9am" "10am" "11am" "12am" "1pm" "2pm" "3pm" "4pm" "5pm" "6pm" "7pm" "8pm" "9pm" "10pm" "11pm" "12pm"]
  set current-phase first all-phases

  set phase-counter 1
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;; Create people ;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to setup-people
  create-people population
  ask people[
    move-to one-of ( patches with [pcolor = [100 200 236] or pcolor =[150 200 230] or pcolor = [150 255 230] ])
    set count-down 8
  ]
  ask people[
        if random 100 < percent-female [set is-female? true]
   ask people [
    set random-number random 100]

    ask people
    [if random-number <= 31 [set age 10]]
    ask people
    [if ((random-number > 31) and (random-number <= 37)) [set age 25]]
    ask people
    [if ((random-number > 37) and (random-number <= 50)) [set age 35]]
    ask people
    [if ((random-number > 36) and (random-number <= 75)) [set age 45]]
    ask people
    [if ((random-number > 75) and (random-number <= 81)) [set age 55]]
    ask people
    [if ((random-number > 81) and (random-number <= 87)) [set age 65]]
     ask people
    [if ((random-number > 87) ) [set age 75]]

  ]

end

to setup-daily-activies
  let commercial-pickup people with [is-commercial? ]
  let residential-pickup people with [is-high-residential? or is-low-residential? or is-mid-residential?]
  let commercial-dropoff people with [
    is-commercial?
  ]
  let residential-dropoff people with [
    is-high-residential? or is-low-residential? or is-mid-residential?
  ]
  generate-activity (runresult word "leave-home" current-phase) (residential-pickup) (commercial-dropoff)

 
end



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;; Global Clock ;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to report-current-phase
  ; there are a total of 24 hour in a day
  ; so in case of the counter is exceeding 24
  ; set the counter back to 0
  if ticks >= 1[
    set current-phase item phase-counter all-phases
    set phase-counter phase-counter + 1
    if phase-counter mod 24 = 0 [
    set daycounter daycounter + 1
  ]
  ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;; people movement ;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to generate-activity [some-prob origin destination]
  if random-float 1 < some-prob [
    ask people [
        set destination-patch-passenger one-of destination
        set d-xcor [pxcor] of destination-patch-passenger
        set d-ycor [pycor] of destination-patch-passenger
      
    ]
  ]
end



to people-movement
    setup-daily-activies
  ask people [
    ifelse age <= 18 and phase-counter >= 8 and phase-counter <= 15 
    [setxy 0 0]
    [move-to one-of ( patches with [pcolor = [100 200 236] or pcolor =[150 200 230] or pcolor = [150 255 230] ])
  ]
  ]
  ask people with [age > 18]
  [let current-xcor [xcor] of self
      let current-ycor [ycor] of self

  ; destination location coordintes
      let destination-xcor1 [d-xcor] of self
      let destination-ycor1 [d-ycor] of self
    setxy d-xcor d-ycor
   ifelse (current-xcor = destination-xcor1) and
     (current-ycor = destination-ycor1)
  [continue]
      [stay]]
end
 

To continue   
   let current-xcor [xcor] of self
      let current-ycor [ycor] of self

  ; destination location coordintes
      let destination-xcor1 [d-xcor] of self
      let destination-ycor1 [d-ycor] of self
    setxy d-xcor d-ycor
end


to stay   
  set count-down count-down - 1   ;decrement-timer
  set label count-down    
  if count-down = 0 
    [
      Continue
      set label ""
      reset-count-down
    ]    

end

to reset-count-down   
  set count-down 8 
end
```

I looked at a bunch of different explanations on this website like a count-down timer before the person moves again.  I have them stay on the patch for 8 ticks/hours.  I know there are probably many issues in the code but it worked for a little bit before I started getting the nobody error.  So I am asking how I can give a person a destination to stay where they are if they don't get they meet the probability to move to work or home.   I hope this is enough information but if it is not just ask and I give more.